# Downloading an old version of iPhoto onto Mac OSX Lion (10.7)

Tags: macos, photos.app

I'm in a very frustrating situation. About a year ago I acquired a white Macbook (model A1181, 2007 version) running OS X Lion. I was using it happily until last week, when my hard drive suddenly failed. I installed a new drive into it, and got it going again, though I had to start from scratch. A lot of my stuff is saved in Google Drive, so for the most part I was ok, but one really annoying thing is that iPhoto was no longer on my computer, which I use quite a bit. I went to the App Store to re-download it, but it said you need OS X 10.10 to download iPhoto. And my computer doesn't support any OS past 10.7. So I'm kind of stuck. I don't know what to do, but I need iPhoto. It seems ridiculous to get a whole new computer for just a single app, and one that I had before my hard drive failed! Is there any place I can download an older version of iPhoto?

PS, I'm having the same issue trying to download 1Password and Pixelmator. I was able to get a 30-day trial of pixelmator online, which I'm using for now.

Comment: how did you restore your disk? did you use the cmd-r

Comment: I can't remember exactly, but I think that's it. Just where it shows your disks and lets you choose. But that doesn't matter.

Comment: If you have a "approved" version of OS X then it should offer you to get application (for free) that came with it.

Comment: What do you mean "approved"? I don't see any reason why mine wouldn't be approved. Where do I go to get that?

Comment: When you log in to app store it checks your os x installation and approves apple downloads for that os x and above. But that should be no problem for you, just use the original Disk that came with computer, the iphoto is on it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a download link for an older version of iPhoto: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1589?locale=en_EN (*this is an update only*; you still need the original, older iPhoto software to support this or it will not work.)

These are the release notes:

> What's New in Version 9.4
>
> Adds support for Shared Photo Streams on OS X Mountain Lion Comments
>   can now be added to photos after publishing them to Facebook New card
>   and calendar themes have been added A new File menu command can be
>   used to open the current photo library in Aperture (if installed)
>   Includes performance and stability improvements
>
> Post Date: Sep 19, 2012
>
> File Size: 757.61 MB

Answer (score -3):

This link worked for me. I have an older Lion and cant upgrade either. Good Luck. http://support.apple.com/downloads/#iphoto

Comment: That page only downloads the upgraders, not the full app